# A question about 'Past Perfect'

Tags: past-perfect

I'd appreciate if anyone could explain to me the usage of past perfect in the following sentence, since the past perfect, I assume, is unusually referring to '***later*** ***past***'.

> "The frustrated interrogator ***was*** not going to give up easily. “Are you both still working in the company?” Barbara, appearing not the least disturbed by the woman’s incontinent insistence, ***scooped*** the last cherry out of her dish, smiled, ***looked*** directly at her, and ***said*** in the identical tone of voice, “We’ve separated, but the company is unaffected.” That ***shut*** her up. Barbara ***had shown*** her big winner’s badge by using “The Broken Record” technique, the most effective way to curtail an unwelcome cross-examination."

(https://howtotalktoanyone.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-respond-when-you-dont-want-to.html)

Comment: There are two events, one later than another. The later one was the last event in the narrative: _That shut her up_, i.e, she stopped talking. The prior one, with past perfect, is _Barbara had show her ... badge_, which describes the previous events and their outcome. As it happens in this paragraph, the last sentence describes prior events, not the latest one. Order of mention is not always order of occurrence.

Comment: In fact, one of the times when English speakers are very likely to use the past perfect is when the order of mention is not the order of occurrence. Here, the *had shown* happens before *that shut her up*, but after many of the previous verbs.

Comment: It may be moderately helpful to understand that "perfect", in this context, refers to something being "perfected" in the sense of being complete and done with.  This is a rather arcane meaning that is not commonly used outside of arcane English rule books.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it in terms of cause and effect. Here the past perfect is expressing the causal relation (by making explicit their relation to each other in time).  The cause ususally comes before the effect in time.

More simply, the interrogator quit talking *because* Barbara showed her 'big winner's badge' (whatever that is). The cause (showing badge/using technique) precedes the effect (going quiet) and thus comes before it in time. 
The past perfect here is stressing the causality, by putting the first event directly in front of the second, consequential one.